# How to add google play service in android project?

Tags: android

[image]

In library Google play service did not add in andorid example.how to solve this problem.

Comment: when you import select "copy to workspace".

Answer (score 0):

Copy your google play service library inside your workspace and folle below step.

Just Right click on project then select BuildPath then Configure Buildpath inside buildpath, click on Libraries then Click on Add External JARs and add this google-map or whatever jar file which you need. and you are done...

Answer (score 0):

see the link below :-

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/google-maps-in-android-application-with-new-google-maps-android-api-v2-using-supportmapfragment/

and then just link your library in your project to get access .

Comment: i follow same link.but whenever i add googlr play service then it will not add properly.

Comment: when you are importing the project in eclipse just check for copy projects into workspace and then check it.

Comment: file->import->existing android code into workspace->add Google play library file.add select Is library option.then right click on mainproject and add google play service

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add in this manner and have the Google play service in the same workspace
[image][image]

Comment: when i have same steps follow but when i closed this window and reopen then show above window.In the Project ? mark show.please help me.